# Where was Camp David set up for The West Wing?

Tags: film-location, the-west-wing

What location doubled as a stand-in for Camp David specifically for *The West Wing's* Season 6, Episode 2: The Birnam Wood? It appears to be an outdoor location and not a closed set, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Doing some research, I have come up with [Little Hunting Creek](http://www.westwingepguide.com/S6/Episodes/114_TBW.html) described as **"The Back Drop"** for the episode.

> **Little Hunting Creek served as the backdrop for an on-location shoot
> for NBC's "The West Wing."**
>
> **Baltimore fly fishing expert Theaux LeGardeur, who helped script
> fishing scenes,** kept busy between takes Monday by tossing cicadas into
> the stream. Each was devoured instantly by the trout in the
> well-stocked section of the stream.
>
> As LeGardeur prepared to teach actress Lily Tomlin the basics of fly
> fishing, he wore a few home-tied flies on his chest that resembled
> cicadas.
>
> "I think we'll catch one today," LeGardeur told The Frederick
> News-Post. "Ladies are lucky at fishing."
>
> Tomlin, who plays the president's secretary on the series, said she
> was enjoying the surroundings.
>
> "I'm going to buy this place," joked Tomlin, referring to the remote
> lodge near the Camp David presidential retreat in Western Maryland.
> "Right now I'm haggling over the price."
>
> Martin Sheen, who plays President Josiah Bartlet on the series, didn't
> fish, saying he didn't want to disturb the fish in their natural
> environment.
>
> "I don't fish," said Sheen. "I think fish belong where they belong."

As for other filming locations, [The West Wing Fandom Wiki](https://westwing.fandom.com/wiki/The_Birnam_Wood) sites that some of the interior scenes were shot near the actual Camp David!

> Some interior scenes were shot at the **Thorpewood Retreat Center**, in
> the Catoctin Mountains near Thurmont, MD - the actual "Camp David."
> Visit the Thorpewood site here

And according to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0745687/locations), several scenes were shot at **Warner Brothers Burbank Studios** on a few stages: 23, 28, 28A, and 29

Answer (score 0):

The Whitehouse and Camp David Helicopter scenes were filmed at Maple Run Golf Club in Thurmont MD. The Helicopter struck a branch on the first day and was stuck only doing ground runs for the shoot. Subsequently, a tree had to be removed in order to tow the helicopter to the Camp David landing sight on the other side of the Golf Course.

[image: Helicopter]